# How do I create a radio button type group of image buttons that were generated by a for loop in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'm currently having trouble making this piece of code work the way I need it to. Essentially I need it to work very much like a radio button wherein the selected 'node' (by mouseclick) changes to a different image. [image: It should end up looking like this]

The nodes are generated by a for loop, and the amount of nodes depends on some external inputs. There are binds for hover images for each of these buttons. My two current attempts have been to essentially add a command to the nodes within the for loop that determines which button was pressed (using the index of the input list) and use grid to put another image on-top of the node in the same grid space. This half works, but seems to remove all the other nodes temporarily until i activate the hover binds. The runNodes list was part of an older solution that had pretty much the same result as this. I left it in there temporarily in order to be able to reference the nodes, but I'm not even sure if I was doing that correctly.

Alternatively I tried to add another bind to the custom button class I made, wherein upon mouse click, the image changes to the selected image. Unfortunately, this gets removed by the hover binds when the mouse moves off the node.

I have a feeling that one or both these solutions could work, but I'm missing something in my code that would make them work.. however I am also open to completely alternate solutions. I've included as much code as I thought was relevant, but please let me know if more information is needed. The code provided below represents the former of my two solutions. The latter simply involved creating another function similar to hoverOn and hoverOff that used the mouseclick bind. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
  class AttackPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, nodes):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # AttackPage widgets
        self.activeAttack = ActiveAttack(attackSelect)
        self.attackBox = tk.Frame(self, bg=bgCol)
        self.graphicLabel = tk.Label(self.attackBox, bg=bgCol)

        self.nodeFrame = tk.Label(self.attackBox, bg=bgCol)
        self.nodeYellow = tk.PhotoImage(file='img/nodeYellow.png')
        self.nodeYellow_s = tk.PhotoImage(file='img/nodeYellow_s.png')
        self.nodeWhite = tk.PhotoImage(file='img/nodeWhite.png')
        self.nodeSel = tk.PhotoImage(file='img/nodeSel.png')

        self.runNodes = []
        for index, item in enumerate(nodes):
            self.node = NodeDraw(self, index)

            self.nodeFrame.grid_columnconfigure(index + 1, weight=1)
            self.runNodes.append(self.node)

        self.nodeFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
        self.nodeFrame.grid_columnconfigure(len(nodes) + 1, weight=3)

        self.contextBorder = tk.Label(self.attackBox, bg='#FFFFFF', height=25)
        self.context = tk.Text(self.attackBox, height=1, width=1, background=windowCol, foreground='#FFFFFF', wrap='word', font='calibri 10',
                                highlightthickness=4, highlightcolor=windowCol, highlightbackground=windowCol, relief='flat',
                                selectbackground=sapienYellow, selectforeground='#000000')

        self.terminalFrame = tk.Label(self.attackBox, bg=windowCol)
        self.terminalTitleImg = tk.PhotoImage(file='img/terminalTitle.png')
        self.terminalTitle = tk.Label(self.terminalFrame, image=self.terminalTitleImg, borderwidth=0, bg=windowCol)
        self.terminal = tk.Text(self.terminalFrame, height=9, width=160, background=windowCol, foreground='#FFFFFF',
                                wrap='word', font='calibri 10', highlightthickness=4, highlightcolor=windowCol,
                                highlightbackground=windowCol, relief='flat', selectbackground=sapienYellow,
                                selectforeground='#000000')

        # AttackPage layout
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=10)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=10)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.attackBox.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.attackBox.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.attackBox.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.attackBox.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
        self.attackBox.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.graphicLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=(12, 6), pady=(12, 6))

        self.nodeFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=(12, 6), pady=(6, 12))

        self.contextBorder.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew', padx=(6, 12), pady=(12, 0))
        self.context.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky='nsew', padx=(7, 13), pady=(13, 0))

        self.terminalFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew', padx=(12, 12), pady=(6, 12))
        self.terminalTitle.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nw', padx=3, pady=3)
        self.terminal.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

class NodeDraw:
    def __init__(self, controller, index):

        self.inactive = HoverButton(controller.nodeFrame, 'img/nodeWhite.png', 'img/nodeYellow.png', 0)
        self.inactive.configure(image=controller.nodeYellow, borderwidth=0, bg=bgCol, activebackground=bgCol, command=lambda: self.selectNode(controller, index))
        self.inactive.grid(row=0, column=index + 1)
        controller.nodeFrame.grid_columnconfigure(index + 1, weight=1)

    def selectNode(self, controller, index):
        self.selectNode = tk.Label(controller.nodeFrame)
        self.selectNode.configure(image=controller.nodeSel, borderwidth=0, bg=bgCol, activebackground=bgCol)
        self.selectNode.grid(row=0, column=index+1)

class HoverButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, hovImg, img, bg):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, parent)
        self.image = None
        self.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: self.hoverOn(hovImg, self, bg))
        self.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: self.hoverOff(img, self, bg))
   
    def hoverOn(self, img, var, bg):  # hover image, button variable, background change (bool - 0 = no change to bgcolor)
        hoverImg = tk.PhotoImage(file=img)
        var.configure(image=hoverImg)
        var.image = hoverImg
        if bg == 1:
            var.configure(bg=sapienYellow)

    # Hover over button revert
    def hoverOff(self, img, var, bg):
        returnImg = tk.PhotoImage(file=img)
        var.configure(image=returnImg)
        var.image = returnImg
        if bg == 1:
            var.configure(bg=windowCol)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that uses an actual `Radiobutton`. Simply change everywhere I wrote the word `text` to the word `image` instead (3 places). Then uncomment the `images` `dict` and change all the paths to be correct. I dont have your images, nor do I intend to make some so, I made this work with text. There are zero reasons why it wont work with images instead.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = tk.Tk()

#the radiobutton
class Statebutton(tk.Radiobutton):
    def __init__(self, master, variable, **kwargs):
        tk.Radiobutton.__init__(self, master, **{**kwargs, 'variable':variable, 'indicatoron':0})

        #delete this line ~ only for text version purposes
        self.configure(width=5)
        
        self.__bound = False
        self.__bind_names  = ['<Enter>', '<Leave>', '<1>']
        self.__bind_states = ['hover', 'up', 'down']
        self.__bind_ids    = [None]*3
        
        self.__var = variable
        self.__var.trace('w', self.__adjust)
        self.__adjust()
    
    #bind all events ~ change "text" to "image" at the end of the lambda
    def __bindings(self):
        for i, (name, state) in enumerate(zip(self.__bind_names, self.__bind_states)):
            self.__bind_ids[i] = self.bind(name, lambda e, s=state:self.configure(text=s))
        self.__bound = True
        
    #unbind all events
    def __unbindings(self):
        if self.__bound:
            for name, id in zip(self.__bind_names, self.__bind_ids):
                self.unbind(name, id)
            self.__bound = False
        
    def __adjust(self, *args):
        if self.__var.get() == self['value']:
            #change "text" to "image"
            self['text'] = 'sel'    
            if self.__bound:
                self.__unbindings()
        else:
            if not self.__bound:
                #change "text" to "image"
                self['text'] = 'up'
                self.__bindings()
        

selection = tk.StringVar()
selection.set('3')

#uncomment the below and adjust paths ~ DO NOT CHANGE the "name" argument
#images = dict(
#    up=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('up.png'), name='up'),
#    hover=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('hover.png'), name='hover'),
#    down=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('down.png'), name='down'),
#    sel=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('selected.png'), name='sel'),
#)

#the loop
for n in range(4):
    Statebutton(root, variable=selection, value=f'{n}').grid(row=0, column=n)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this is awsome ! i never thought tkinter is this cool

Comment: This seems to work well thankyou! Is there a way to add another state(s) for the button that activates when another variable is true, and another state for when that variable is true AND the button has been selected? This is depicting a process and each node is an action in that process. I want to have an indication of which node is active but allow the user to select any of the nodes